# Proving that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=f''(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Prove that $$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=f''(x)$$

Is the following a correct proof:

> $f''(x)=$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(x-h)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$

I would really love input on this proof. The book "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics" solves it differently.

Comment: No your prove isn't right whit definition of *lim*.

Comment: welcome to [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com). Please write the answer in the book if you can't say someone other give the correct prove or change your question.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect, sorry: you can't simply change $f'(x)$ into $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$, because $f'(x)$ is a limit and not that expression.

Comment: There is no correct proof of the statement, since a second derivative requires two limits of 2 different variables to define.  Your statement might be true if you added "if the second derivative is defined, then ... = ..."

Comment: @egreg- Can't we make that change if $f'(x)$ exists and is finite?

Answer (score 2):

Summing up
$$f(x+h) - f(x) = \  h f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + o(h^3)$$
$$f(x-h) - f(x) = - h f'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}f''(x) + o(h^3)$$
 you get
$$f(x+h) + f(x-h) -2f(x) = h^2 f''(x) + o(h^3)$$
which is equivalent to
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) + f(x-h) -2f(x)}{h^2} = f''(x)$$

However I think this is the proof your book gives, since this is quite standard.

Comment: Yes this is indeed the proof that my book gives. However, I'd like a critique of my proof as given in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is incorrect. You can say
\begin{align}
f''(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(x-h)}{h}\\[10px]
&=
\lim_{h\to 0}
\dfrac{
\lim\limits_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}
-
\lim\limits_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(x-h+k)-f(x-h)}{k}
}
{
h
}
\end{align}
but at this point you're almost stuck. You could unify the two limits at the numerator and work on it, but at the end you still have a double limit.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use L'Hospital rule twice

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}\\=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f'(x+h)-f'(x-h)}{2h}\\=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f''(x+h)+f''(x-h)}{2}\\=f''(x)$