# Question about Indeterminate form and Taylor's theorem

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, indeterminate-forms

In my textbook, there is a problem in chapter **Expansion of a Function** that is

If $f''$ is continuous on some NBD of $c$ prove that,

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(c+h) - 2f(c) + f(c-h)}{h^2} = f''(c)$

In another chapter **Indeterminate Form** there is a same looking problem 
where $f(x)$ is twice differentiable in an NBD of $a$ then the same limit function is given.

My Thinking: These two questions are very same because if a function is differentiable then it is continuous too but not conversely.

I solved it by Taylor 's theorem with $R_2$ and the remainder in Lagrange's form.

But it has been seen that it could be solved by L'Hospital rule, I want to know how.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1141952/385242

Comment: thank you so much. It helps me a lot. @Itay4